# IIS 7.5 applicationHost.config file is not being updated

Tags: iis-7.5, mime-types, applicationhost

I'm currently playing around with the Microsoft.Web.Administration (MWA) namespace in order to adjust our application to configure IIS 7.5 with the new API.
I understood that all IIS level changes should be expressed in the following file (I'm on Win2K8-R2):

```
%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

So, when I use the `ServerManager` object to commit the configuration changes the file should be updated accordingly.

After adding a new MIME type (programmatic with MWA) I did not see any changes in the `applicationHost.config file`, but I do see the new MIME type in the IIS manager window and IIS recognizes this MIME type without problems. Even after restating the OS - The config file does not contain the newly added MIME type, but the IIS manager window does list it.

Because my application pools are forced to 32-bit (`Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true`), I thought that the related config file should be located under `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config`, but (if it exists...) - it also does not change after the code commits the updates.

Can someone please explain this? Am I missing something (looking at the wrong file maybe?)? Can someone please shed some light on the `SysWOW64\inetsrv\config` directory?

This is my code for adding the MIME type:

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
ConfigurationElementCollection staticContentCollection = manager
    .GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
    .GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent")
    .GetCollection();

//MIMETypes is a string[] array, each object is {FileExt},{MIMETypeStr}
foreach (string pair in MIMETypes)
{
    string[] mimeProps = pair.Split(',');

    ConfigurationElement mimeTypeEl = staticContentCollection
          .Where(a => 
                   (string)a.Attributes["fileExtension"].Value == mimeProps[0])
          .FirstOrDefault();


    if (mimeTypeEl != null)
    {
        staticContentCollection.Remove(mimeTypeEl);
    }

    ConfigurationElement mimeMapElement = 
                  staticContentCollection.CreateElement("mimeMap");

    mimeMapElement["fileExtension"] = mimeProps[0];
    mimeMapElement["mimeType"] = mimeProps[1];

    staticContentCollection.Add(mimeMapElement);
}

manager.CommitChanges();

//At this point all is working but the config file does not reflect the change
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just tried your code and it works fine. You are aware that this mime type is being added to the global mime type collection and not to a site?

It also gets added to the end of the `<staticContent>` list, this list isn't re-sorted when you do `ServerManager.CommitChanges()`.

Also on Windows 2008-R2 the correct location for `applicationHost.config` is at:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
```

I'm guess you're either using notepad.exe or NotePad2 to open this file (32 bit editors can't open it). Notepad won't reload the file upon a change and NotePad2 needs to be told to display a file change notification (alt-F5), out of the box it won't.

Also try adding something unusual like `.xxx`, run your update then open the config file and do a search. I guarantee it'll be there.

**Update:**

Further to your comments below, I'm not sure how you're able to open `applicationHost.config` using NotePad++ or any 32-bit editor, I certainly can't. Can you download NotePad2 which is a 64-bit editor:

> http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html

The release candidate works just fine.

On a default install of any 64 bit Windows 2008 or Windows 7 there shouldn't be an `applicationHost.config` in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config` folder. I'm not sure why you'd be seeing one there.

Comment: Hi & thanks for the quick reply :-) The MIME type should be added to the <syste.Webserver>/<staticContent> node as a <mimeMap fileExtension=""" mimeType=""/> node. But again... The code is working, I can see the new type in IIS manager (GUI), but the applicationHost.config file is unchanged, that is, does not contain the new <mimeMap ... /> node anywhere. Even adding something unusual like ".xxx,application/BlaBla" is successful but the config file is unchanged. I'm using Notepad++ or the Visual Studio (10) XML editor to view the file (both apps are 32bit).

Comment: I'm sure I'm viewing the right file (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config). What do you mean by saying "...this list isn't re-sorted when you do ServerManager.CommitChanges()". Please explain...

Comment: I've checked it again, with an emphasis on the text viewer. If I open the config file with Notepad++ or VS2010 (both 32bit) - The changes are not there. But... If I open the file with the native Notepad application (64bit) the changes are there! Something does not smell OK here... Seems like the FS redirection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) or this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589, are somehow not playing very well... Any suggestions for a 64bit text editor?

Comment: Thanks man! NotePad2 seems just fine & working as expected! Cheers :-)

Comment: There's also a hack way of opening up the applicationHost.config file in 32-bit apps by abusing UNC paths. Instead of navigating to the directory on disk, use the UNC path (eg. \\192.168.1.100\C$\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config)

Comment: @smaglio81 - I never knew about that one. Cheers.

Comment: That editing the file using a 64-bit editor instead of a 32-editor is a new level of voodoo.

Comment: @Kev: The most useful thing I've read all day. Who'd have thought that using a 32-bit app would not open/save correctly.

Comment: Another way to access this file without using a UNC path, is to use the [Sysnative alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx): `notepad++ %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` (You cannot go to this path with explorer, because it's only visible to 32-bit applications)

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround to open and edit the 64-bit IIS configuration files with your favorite 32-bit editor that is 64-bit compatible (i.e. Notepad++), you can create a Windows directory symbolic link which points to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config`. With this method, you are *replacing* the 32-bit `Config` directory, located at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config` to point to the 64-bit version. If, for example, you have an application which requires both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, this method won't work.

For more information, I strongly encourage you to visit [this MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2008/10/27/using-visual-studio-2008-on-a-64-bit-computer-to-edit-applicationhost-config.aspx).